# Text mining on mobile

Tags: android

I have some text files or html file. I want to retrieve some words from the text. My worry is that I have to do text-mining on mobile. Which algorithm can I use for text-mining on a mobile. A sample example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you need to do text mining on mobile, because the algorithms are mostly trained on servers on the cloud. Besides that, if you have a lot of files, you can overload the cellphone CPU.

If you have a few files, why don't you use regex?

Its difficult to give an example because you gave too little information about the case.
I think that you need to Google better this before, and return with a more especific question.